# if IQ is inherited, is it from father or mother?

Tags: intelligence, iq, genetics

I think there is some research that IQ is inherited, but is it inherited more from the father, or mother, or both?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  You said you **think** there is some research that IQ is inherited, but have you found any research to back that up? We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: THis is about prior research: https://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/children-intelligence-iq-mother-inherit-inheritance-genetics-genes-a7345596.html.
I didn't register account, hence comment.

Answer (score 2):

Both.  The Independent article used a blog post as its main source.  The blog post (which is no longer online) claimed to rely on a doc (scientific document) that **actually** hardly supports its main assertion.  What that doc **actually** found was that there are 41 genes on the X chromosome associated with mental retardation, and none on the Y chromosome, and many (but well under 41) such genes on each of the other 22 chromosomes.  These autosomes had a total of 180 such genes.  ([My source](https://sci-hub.tw/10.1016/S0168-9525(01)02446-5) for the doc)  The doc then goes on to make a bunch of conclusions based on "assuming that these [41] genes are responsible for the development of general intelligence or cognitive abilities (‘g’ according to Plomin)", but this is a totally unwarranted assumption in my view.  Oh, and the doc is in the Opinion section, so it's probably NOT peer-reviewed, which is why I call it a **doc** rather than a paper.

Comment: Thanks can you please provide some reading or back up your claim that it is inherited from Both?

Comment: Huh? Can you not use or see the link to my source provided in my answer!  How could you not? Anyone?